# MVVM Set Recyclerview Adapter With Items In Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I am using MVVM pattern with retrofit and recyclerview for the first time. I have  made the network call in my viewmodel class but have no idea how to display the data in recyclerview.

Here's my viewmodel code:

```
public class HomeSessionsViewModel extends ViewModel {

private static final String TAG = HomeSessionsViewModel.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;

public String sessionImg;
public String title, programName, batchName, batchPlayersCount;

public HomeSessionsViewModel(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void fetchSessions(String coachId){
    Log.d(TAG, "Call made");
    Call<SessionDetails> call = RestClient.getRestInstance()
            .getSessionsService()
            .fetchSessions(coachId);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<SessionDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SessionDetails> call, Response<SessionDetails> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                SessionDetails details = response.body();
                List<Sessions> sessions = details.getSessions();
                for (int i = 0; i < sessions.size(); i++){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Session Name:\t" + sessions.get(i).session_name);
                    sessionImg = sessions.get(i).sessionImage;
                    title = sessions.get(i).session_name;
                    programName = sessions.get(i).program_name;
                    batchName = sessions.get(i).batch_name;
                    batchPlayersCount = sessions.get(i).participants_count;
        //          addData(sessions);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SessionDetails> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't Get Sessions:\n");
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}

}
```

and adapter code:

```
public class SessionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SessionsViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
private List<HomeSessionsViewModel> itemsList;

public SessionsAdapter(Context context, List<HomeSessionsViewModel> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@Override
public SessionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    HomeSessionsBinding sessionsBinding = HomeSessionsBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
    return new SessionsViewHolder(sessionsBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SessionsViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
    HomeSessionsViewModel viewModel = itemsList.get(position);
    viewholder.bindSessions(viewModel);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}

}
```

and in my fragment I have this:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickedListener, DatePickerListener {

private RecyclerView actionsRV, sessionsRV;
private List<ActionsViewModel> actionsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ActionsAdapter actionsAdapter;

private HomeFragmentBinding fragmentBinding;
private HomeFragmentViewModel homeViewModel;
private HomeSessionsViewModel sessionsViewModel;

private List<HomeSessionsViewModel> sessionsViewModelList = new ArrayList<>();
private SessionsAdapter sessionsAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    homeViewModel = new HomeFragmentViewModel(getActivity());
    fragmentBinding.setHomeViewModel(homeViewModel);
    init();
    return fragmentBinding.getRoot();
}

private void init() {
    addActions();
    initPicker();
    populateSessions();
}

private void initPicker() {
    fragmentBinding.datePicker.setListener(this)
            .setMonthAndYearTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            .setDateSelectedColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            .setDateSelectedTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_03))
            .setTodayButtonTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            .setTodayDateTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.accent))
            .setUnselectedDayTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            .init();
}

private void populateSessions() {
    sessionsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeSessionsViewModel.class);
    sessionsViewModel.fetchSessions("4086");
  //sessionsViewModel.fetchSessions();
  //sessionsViewModel.fetchSessions(""); // TODO: 3/16/2019 Use coach id from db

    sessionsRV = fragmentBinding.sessionsRV;
  //sessionsViewModelList = sessionsViewModel.items();
    sessionsAdapter = new SessionsAdapter(getActivity(), sessionsViewModelList);


}

private void addActions() {
    actionsRV = fragmentBinding.actionsRV;
    actionsRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager hlm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    fragmentBinding.actionsRV.setLayoutManager(hlm);

    ActionsViewModel action1 = new ActionsViewModel();
    action1.name = "Attendance";
    action1.img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_attendance);
    actionsList.add(action1);

    ActionsViewModel action2 = new ActionsViewModel();
    action2.name = "Evaluate";
    action2.img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_evaluate);
    actionsList.add(action2);

    ActionsViewModel action3 = new ActionsViewModel();
    action3.name = "Players";
    action3.img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_players);
    actionsList.add(action3);

    ActionsViewModel action4 = new ActionsViewModel();
    action4.name = "Programs";
    action4.img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_programs);
    actionsList.add(action4);

    ActionsViewModel action5 = new ActionsViewModel();
    action5.name = "Tips/VOD";
    action5.img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tips_vod);
    actionsList.add(action5);

    actionsAdapter = new ActionsAdapter(getActivity(), actionsList);
    actionsAdapter.setItemClickedListener(this);
    actionsRV.setAdapter(actionsAdapter);

}

@Override
public void itemClicked(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Attendance Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Evaluate Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Players Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 3:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Programs Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 4:
            Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Tips Coming Soon", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDateSelected(DateTime dateSelected) {

}
}
```

Displaying the actions recyclerview was straightforward but I'm not sure how to go about the sessions. I have followed [this tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CILoRE9EGM&index=10&list=PL7CGVRj_4Ua2NaDtP_gLyaUragjrDYlw4) but I'm stuck how to get the data from viewmodel into fragment recyclerview. I have read that adding view widgets into viewmodel can cause memory leaks. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LiveData for these kind of purposes. LiveData is Lifecycle aware and can be used in ViewModel.

In your `ViewModel`, add a property of type `MutableLiveData`.

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Session>> sessionsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<List<Session>>();

public LiveData<List<Session>> getSessionLiveData(){
    return sessionsLiveData;
}
```

Set value to this `LiveData` when network call is made and you have required data for the adapter.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<SessionDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SessionDetails> call, Response<SessionDetails> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                SessionDetails details = response.body();
                List<Session> sessions = details.getSessions();
                sessionsLiveData.postValue(sessions);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SessionDetails> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't Get Sessions:\n");
            Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

In your Fragment, observer this `LiveData`.

```
viewModel.getSessionLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Session>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Session> sessions) {
                // set Data to adapter here.
                adapter.setData(sessions);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your code will work if I change the adapter list class to Sessions but here I'm using the vewmodel as list class. How will this combine with your code. I'll accept your answer if you can tell me this, as I have used databinding for the adapter. Thank you.

Comment: I refactored my adapter and viewholder to remove databinding and it worked. Thanks but if there's a way to use databinding with MVVMR3 (retrofit, room and recyclerview) I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @DarthPlagueris Know that you shouldn't be using your `ViewModel` as list class. It is not a good practice. Using DataBinding, you can bind your items of list to your `RecyclerView` item on UI. But that doesn't mean that whenever you get new list from api and it will be bound directly with your `RecyclerView`. DataBinding helps when you want to make changes to the data and don't want to refresh whole adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I blindly followed a tutorial but internally I wasn't comfortable with that approach. Thanks again and is it possible to use MVVM pattern with DialogFragments?

Comment: @DarthPlagueris Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Ok, good info sir. I have a dialog fragment (PARENT) which hosts a tabbed dialog fragment (TABBED-CHILD) with recyclerview and checkbox for two tabs. How do I transfer the checked items from each tab backwards to the PARENT? Can viewmodel work here or I have to go from TABBED-CHILD fragment to PARENT?

Comment: @DarthPlagueris For this scenario, you can share your PARENT's `ViewModel` to the TABBED-CHILD and when you want to collect checked list, you can maintain a property(list of checked items) in `ViewModel` and then you can update/populate it with checked items. The same list will be available to the PARENT as everyone here is sharing the `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks but how do I share viewmodel across activities/fragments in this case? I can't find any useful links.

Comment: @DarthPlagueris Suppose PARENT-ViewModel: ParentDialogVM. CHILDS-VM: ChildViewModel1, ChildViewModel2. Then when you initialize `ViewModel` for everyone this same way: `ParentDialogVM viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ParentDialogVM.class);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190253/discussion-between-darth-plagueris-and-birju-vachhani).

Comment: How is this related to Adapter in OP's question?